# Написать условие

Tags: c#

Есть простая строка `string stroka="qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbm";//случайный набор символов`
далее..

```
string mystr=Console.ReadLine();
```

Переформулирую вопрос: я с клавиатуры ввел любой текст (строка mystr), и код показывает имеется ли в моей строке, которую я ввел с клавы, хоть какой нибудь символ ИЗ строки string, если да то условие идет, если нет, то тогда ничего не происходит

Answer (score 1):

ну тут то всё просто:

```
// Ваша строка
string mystr = console.Readine();
// Ваша подстрока
string subMyStr = "blablabla";

// Содержит ли строка подстроку
if (mystr.Contains(subMyStr))
{
   // Если содержит - то вот этот блок
}
else 
{
   // Если не содержит - вот этот
}
```

Comment: странно что автор отметил верным, если в вопросе он сказал _хоть какой нибудь символ ИЗ строки_ а здесь полная подстрока ищется

Comment: учитывая что условие сильно поменялось - да ) Сначала автор пишет одно условие, затем переделывает в другое условие. Господин автор - так вот люто тереть комментарии, и менять вопрос - так и карму всю сбить можно

Comment: Да, не увидел, что вопрос редактировался.